# mod rewrite recursion

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to understand why I get an internal server error with this in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)(/)?$ $1.php
  Options +FollowSymlinks
</IfModule>
```

I'm attempting to direct URI's like /about/ and /work/ to about.php and work.php

Here's an example of when I get a 500 error:

I visit example.com/about/probablydoesntexist

I looked at the rewrite log and I can see it keeps trying like so:

about/probablydoesntexist.php
about/probablydoesntexist.php.php
about/probablydoesntexist.php.php.php and so on.

Why isn't it meeting the RewriteCond of that php file not exisiting?

How do I prevent the recursion?

Comment: Is this htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: it is! Maybe there's a better way to rewrite the URI to php files?